# Views duplicating ? - ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently using the `ECSlidingViewController`sample and I'm having a small bug while opening the same view I'm currently in.

For Example if I'm inside `GudjonDaneil` and I open the "drawer" and hit `GudjonDaniel` again the viewDidLoad method calls twice, If I open it again it calls the viewDidLoad 3 times in a row. It seems like the views are stacking above each other. I need someway of killing the class(view) once I open the view again.

Here's what happens once you click on the `-UItableView`

```
 NSLog(@"Channel 1 Loading");
        tableViewCellLoading = true;
        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
            CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstChannel"];
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; }];
```

How the drawer application looks like

http://gyazo.com/f811283fadbad5b50ee4d594b6798f18

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked... but here's an answer for anyone else that is looking.

The following is from my "MenuController.m" file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1);
    UINavigationController *currentNav = (UINavigationController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
    UIViewController *theControllerYouWant = [currentNav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([currentNav.viewControllers count]-1)];
    NSString *CurrentSelectedCViewController = NSStringFromClass(theControllerYouWant.class);

    if (indexPath.row == 1 && ![CurrentSelectedCViewController isEqualToString:@"PeopleTableViewController"]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PeopleView"]]];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2 && ![CurrentSelectedCViewController isEqualToString:@"CompanyPickerController"]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompanyView"]]];
    }
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

The basic explanation is this:

1. Get a reference to the current Navigation Controller
2. Get a reference to the Navigation Controller's top view (always the last view in its
   array)
3. Get a string representation of that view.
4. Depending on which menu cell you clicked on, check if the slidingViewController's
   current top view is the same that you are going to..
5. If it's not the same, load the proper view in to topviewcontroller
6. Close the menu